# Use hidden iframe to submit data

Tags: javascript, iframe, form-submit

I need to submit some information to my servlet. Once I submit this information, I'll receive a PDF from the servlet based on the data. I know I can construct the URL and pass parameters to it using HTTP GET. Suppose my form data is too large.So is it possible to do this using a hidden iFrame? I'll submit the parameters using the hidden iFrame and in my servlet, I write the PDF to the response stream. Will this work? If it works can someone please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set the target to the iframe you want to submit it to.

```
<form action='...' name='theform' target='theiframe'>
  . 
  .
  .
  <iframe name='theiframe' src='...'> 
  </iframe>
</form>
```

This forum post has some details : http://forums.powweb.com/showthread.php?t=77213

Comment: If I understand it correctly, instead of submitting the current loaded page, I'm submitting the information using an iFrame. So the information reaches the server. Now how will it handle the response, will it be loaded inside this iFrame? If the browser already has a PDF plugin, will it be displayed inside iFrame?

Comment: Yes, the response will be to the iframe as well. After rereading your question, I'm wondering why you don't simply POST the form data directly instead of using the iframe.

Comment: I don't want to refresh the whole page. I think I cannot use AJAX when the response type is PDF.

Comment: Well, if your intention is to download the PDF, then the page won't get refreshed. If your intention is to show the PDF in an iframe on some part of the page, then this will work.

Comment: I don't want to show the PDF in an iFrame. If the plugin is there will it display the PDF in iFrame?

Comment: yeah, if the browser can handle the PDF it should show it in the iframe itself.

Comment: For those wondering, there are still (in 2017) a few good reasons to use this approach... for one, B2B systems require a form to POST an XML payload to the server and respond with a URL for redirection.  AJAX isn't viable due to CORS restrictions.  Server to server communication sometimes does not work because Production web servers do not have access to the internets.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, which way do you want to sent the data using your iframe? I think you're limited to either GET or POST there, too. Means, if your data is too large, the iframe won't help sending your data.

What server backend do you use? You might be able to configure the maximum size of request data (post / get).

Please have a look [at this message](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/max-length-post-get-variable-names-t77133.html#p412139) for more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes, using the hidden Iframe method is very old school, almost like before the great days of Ajax methods.

You can use jquery **Ajax call and serialize your full form passing all variables**. Remember to check your request size in your config, in case it post reaches maximum size.

Comment: I totally agree, but I have to use a form framework for a client that doesn't use AJAX. :P We don't always get what we want.