# Chrome doesn't remember input field value

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, preventdefault, input-field

I'm using **HTML code** like this:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="inputFIeld" id="someVal" value="" />
    <button id="submitFun" type="submit">Dodaj</button>
</form>
```

The only thing I do is `preventDefault` on submit button click and then I make an ajax call to the server.

It works just fine on all browsers except chrome. Autocomplete on chrome just doesn't work.

Comment: that drop down thing on input fields

Comment: I solved this chrome bug using invisible iframe.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306640/use-hidden-iframe-to-submit-data][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306640/use-hidden-iframe-to-submit-data

Comment: Can't reproduce (8+ years later), `onclick="event.preventDefault()"` keeps text in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I find a link on chrome site :

Chrome : You should have to activate autocomplete :

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893?hl=en

Comment: tnx for this but it doesnt solve my problem. Some input fields on my site work correctly. I think its because I use ajax call insted of normal post form method.

Comment: strange stuff, i've  just tested in my environment, chrome and chromium, and my ajax call shows the autocomplete.... I know it's not an intelligent thing, but, maybe should you try to reinstall the navigator... to begin... (sorry to can't help you more)