# Trying to CSRF/XSRF test our website - can I use an iframe to POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, csrf

I'm trying to test a specific `POST` endpoint in our website from CSRF attacks.

To do this, I'm trying to use an iFrame. When I `submit` the form the entire page redirects. I was under the impression that the iFrame *window* should only do the form submit, not the *entire* (root?) document?

sample code...

```
<html>
<body>

    <p>
        <h3>CSRF Test.</h3>
        <a href="#" onClick="crossDomainPost();">Click Me</a>
    </p>

    <form id="csrfForm" action="http://www.someWebsite/postTest" method="POST">
        <snipped>
    </form>

    <iframe  name="someiframe"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function crossDomainPost() {
        var iframe = $('#someiframe');

        var form = $('#csrfForm');
        iframe.add(form);

        // Submit the form in the iframe.
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `add()` doesn't put the form in the iframe, it simply adds the element to the jQuery object. Can use `target` on form to be the iframe

Comment: you mean this: `var form = $('#csrfForm'); form.target = "someiframe"; form.submit();` ? (cause that's not working).

Comment: haven't done that for a very long time but should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306640/use-hidden-iframe-to-submit-data

Comment: oh..I see why...`target` isn't a jQuery property...try `form.attr('target', "someiframe")` or `form[0].target = "someiframe"`or simply hard code it as attribute on form tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `target` on the form to be the iframe

```
 <form id="csrfForm" action="url" method="POST" target="someiframe">
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to use Javascript to handle the post (because the the form might not *always* want to target the iFrame..

```
<-- No target attribute here -->
<form id="csrfForm" action="url" method="POST">

...

function crossDomainPost() {       
    var form = $('#csrfForm');
    form[0].target = "someiframe";
    form.submit();
}
```

(Hat Tip: @charlietfl and his comments in the OP).